# Anyone can fix this adding styles to Download button without breaking the working of the Button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add style to the Download button, it looks so formal. want to add some button styles, Can anybody help me with this?

The code is 100% right, just want to make Download button stylish with given styles.

```
                <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <head>
                    <title></title>
                    <style type="text/css">
                body {
                    font-family: Arial;
                    font-size: 10pt;
                }
                </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <input type="button" value="Download" onclick="DelayRedirect()" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <div id="dvCountDown" style="display: none"> You will be redirected after 
                        <span id="lblCount"></span>&nbsp;seconds. 
                    </div>
                    
                </body>
            </html>
```

The CSS i want to add is given below -

```
                <style>
            .button {
              background-color: DodgerBlue;
              border: none;
              color: white;
              padding: 12px 30px;
              cursor: pointer;
              font-size: 20px;
            }
            
            /* Darker background on mouse-over */
            .button:hover {
              background-color: RoyalBlue;
            }
            </style>
```

Comment: and the css you provided didnt work?

Comment: @RamondeVries CSS is working 100% fine, separately with another HTML code but didn't work with the above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any attribution for your button. Use:

```css
input[type="button"]{ /*<-- this is how you refer to an element like INPUT */
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
}
input[type="button"]:hover {
  background-color: RoyalBlue;
}
```

```html
                    <input type="button" value="Download" onclick="DelayRedirect()" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <div id="dvCountDown" style="display: none"> You will be redirected after 
                        <span id="lblCount"></span>&nbsp;seconds. 
                    </div>
```

**How to refer in styles**

- .className for class
- #idName for id
- elementName for an element

All of which can be used in your input button, like this:

```
<input class="className"......>

<input id="idName".......>

<input.....>
```

**See: [HTML Classes](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp)**

Comment: Thanks for your help buddy :) and for the explanation, I am new in this.. you helped me a lot